# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar estos errores al momento de instalar la librería xlsx en Angular 15.1?

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio, angularjs, xlsx

> Al momento de instalar la **librería xlsx** con **npm install xlsx**, en un proyecto de ***angular ***versión 15.1******, me salen estos errores:

```
➜ npm install xlsx
```

```
 npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve 
 npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
 npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@15.1.2
 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
 npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.1.2" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@15.1.2
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
 npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^15.1.0" from the root project
 npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^15.1.0" from the root project 
 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
 npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
 npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.9
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
 npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.9" from the root project
 npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"15.2.4" from @angular/localize@15.2.4
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
 npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.9
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
 npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.9" from the root project
 npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
 npm ERR!   2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
 npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@15.2.4
 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
 npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
 npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.9
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
 npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.9" from the root project
 npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"15.2.4" from @angular/localize@15.2.4
 npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/localize
 npm ERR!       peerOptional @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.9
 npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
 npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.9" from the root project
```

> Intenté con ***npm install xlsx --save*** pero vuelven a salir los mismos errores.
> Salen esos errores cuando intento instalar la librería xlsx, tengo instalado angular 15.1 y node 18.13, estoy tratando de instalar directamente en Visual Studio Code.
> ¡Me ayudan! ¡por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Para forzar la instalación puedes utilizar `--force`.

`npm install xlsx --force`

El uso de `--save` no es necesario por qué se utiliza por defecto (se instala en las dependencias de producción, no en las de desarrollo)

Si no funciona, puedes intentar con `--legacy-peer-deps`, que es menos seguro y puede instalar dependencias incompatibles entre sí, causar conflictos mayores en actualizaciones posteriores.

---

> ¡Antes de hacer estos cambios versiona el estado actual!

Una propuesta final de solución del problema es resolver cada una de las dependencias que fallan. El mensaje que se presenta te está diciendo que una de las dependencias ya instaladas (no relacionadas al paquete xlsx) no cumple con el requisito solicitado que es `@angular/compiler-cli@15.2.4`. Tu instalación actual es `@angular/compiler@15.1.2`. Una manera burda de solucionar esto es ir a tu `package.json` y modificar las versiones de `@angular/paquete...@15.x.x` para que coincidan todas. Después de eso hacer un `npm install` para sincronizar tu `package-lock.json`.